# Why is my variables linearly dependent? Regression, Diff-n-diff, interaction term and dummies

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression

I've created a small dataframe for testing differences-in-differences, in order to gain some intuition about the method and theory. I guess I have two questions.

1. Why is the correlation between free_cookies and free_cookies*teenager = 1?
2. Is there a way to fix the data so that the regression lm(cookies_eaten ~ teenager + free_cookies + teenager*free_cookies, data), does not drop the interaction term(free_cookies*teenager)?

It should be possible to run a regression with the format

```
outcome ~ dummy1 + dummy2 + dummy1*dummy2
```

and get **coefficient estimates** for all independent variables, which I've seen work elsewhere. To be clear: teenager and free_cookies are dummy variables. I'm guessing I've just done something silly when I constructed my sample data.

```
# cookie eating data
data <- read.table(text = "

year    cookies_eaten   teenager    free_cookies
2000    110 1   0
2001    110 1   0
2002    120 1   0
2003    120 1   0
2004    125 1   0
2005    125 1   0
2006    125 1   0
2007    145 1   1
2008    155 1   1
2009    160 1   1
2010    160 1   1
2000    100 0   0
2001    100 0   0
2002    110 0   0
2003    110 0   0
2004    115 0   0
2005    115 0   0
2006    115 0   0
2007    115 0   0
2008    115 0   0
2009    120 0   0
2010    120 0   0", header=TRUE)


# Regressions
one <- lm(cookies_eaten ~ teenager, data)
summary(one)

two <- lm(cookies_eaten ~ teenager + free_cookies, data)
summary(two)

three <- lm(cookies_eaten ~ teenager + free_cookies + teenager*free_cookies, data)
summary(three) # Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)

# four without free_cookies
four <- lm(cookies_eaten ~ teenager + teenager*free_cookies, data)
summary(four) # Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)

# Corrolation testing
attach(data)
cor(free_cookies, free_cookies*teenager, method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"))
# = 1
cor(cookies_eaten, free_cookies*teenager, method = c("pearson", "kendall", "spearman"))
# = 0.9090648
detach(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the data one can easily see that whenever `teenager == 0` there is also `free_cookies==0` So these data are in perfect alignment. When `teenager==1` every value of `free_cookies` is multiplied by `1` so that does not change anything on `free_cookies` so that is why `free_cookies` and `teenager times free_cookies` is always the same value so the correlation is `1`. With these data you cannot investigate interactions. You need to sample some data where `teenager == 0 and free_cookies ==1`.

```
data <- read.table(text = "
year    cookies_eaten   teenager    free_cookies
2000    110 1   0
2001    110 1   0
2002    120 1   0
2003    120 1   0
2004    125 1   0
2005    125 1   0
2006    125 1   0
2007    145 1   1
2008    155 1   1
2009    160 1   1
2010    160 1   1
2000    100 0   0
2001    100 0   0
2002    110 0   0
2003    110 0   0
2004    115 0   0
2005    115 0   0
2006    115 0   0
2007    115 0   0
2008    115 0   0
2009    120 0   0
2010    120 0   0", header=TRUE)

data$interaction <- data$teenager * data$free_cookies

print(data[, c("free_cookies", "interaction")])

any(data$free_cookies != data$interaction)
```

Comment: Ah! Of course. I added free_cookies = 1 for the same years when teenager == 0. The original problem is solved! Do you mind explaining what any(data$free_cookies != data$interaction) shows?

Comment: Quite literally: Are there *any* cases where `data$free_cookies != data$interaction` ?and R will answer with `FALSE` to say "no, there aren't any". Try `help(any)` and `help(all)` if you are not familiar with these functions. They are very usefull for questions like these once your dataframe gets more rows then fit on your computer screen.